# Unset multiple properties using C# mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this mongo query that I want to run using the C# MongoDB driver:

```
db.test.update(
   { rate: "unknown" },
   { $unset: { qt: "", cost: "", res: "", ... } }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation didn't cover this case, but I'm glad the tests are good enough, though it takes some time to dig into them.
Here's the test where I came to know one can chain multiple `Unset` methods: [TestUnsetTwice](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/b473de06f9bf3587b3a00f52ba2678d9aed71d74/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.Tests/Builders/UpdateBuilderTests.cs#L1039)

Here's my final solution:
Provided a list of properties to update, loop through each property and call the `Unset` method on `UpdateDefinition`.

```
FilterDefinition<TDocument> filterDefinition = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq("rate", "unknown");
UpdateDefinition<TDocument> updateDefinition = null;
UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TDocument> updateDefinitionBuilder = Builders<TDocument>.Update;

foreach (String o in propertiesToDelete)
{
     if(updateDefinition == null)
        updateDefinition = updateDefinitionBuilder.Unset(o);
     else
        updateDefinition = updateDefinition.Unset(o);
}

var collection = GetCollection<TDocument>();
var updateRes = collection.UpdateOne(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
```